# Как отрендерить анимацию с большей частотой кадров но с той же скоростью проигрывания?

Tags: анимация, blender, render, fps

Мне нужно отрендерить анимацию в 60 FPS, но когда я выставляю 60 FPS анимация просто проигрывается быстрее!(https://youtu.be/kJLtdkoFM9A). Я хочу чтобы анимация была с той же скоростью но плавнее.

---

Я нашел способ это сделать - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed и https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dE-485zoCw&feature=emb_logo